# Collections repository implementation with the ability to handle serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have several collections that all look the same but operate on different types of collection items, like this:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Culture")]
public sealed class Cultures : List<LangCult>
{
}
```

The important piece of code here is the `CollectionDataContract` attribute which allows us to serialize this collection into an XML file with `DataContractSerializer`. The entire collection is serialized into one XML file named as the name of the type of collection class, for instance `Cultures.xml`

I would like to come up with a repository, precisely with an interface for a repository, that would work on all of the possible collections, for instance `public class Slugs : List<string>`.

I tried something like this, but I don't know whether it's the best option:

```
public interface ICollectionsRepository<T> where T : IEnumerable
```

Your thoughts?

*Please do not respond with instructions on how to serialize because that is not the issue here and I have it working.*

Comment: And question is? And using List as base class is not good idea. You should use Collection instead. It is specificaly made for extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I should've said I wanted an interface for generic collection with generic items where items have a common base class. This is how I solved it and hopefully someone one day finds it useful.

```
/// <summary>
/// This repo enables us to work with serialisable collections. Collection class has
/// to inherit from IEnumerable and must be described with CollectionDataContract attribute
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public interface ICollectionsRepository<T, V> where T : Collection<V>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Get collection from datastore
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List of items</returns>
    T Load();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Add new collection item to datastore
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Item to be added to the collection</param>
    void Add(V item);
}

public class XmlCollectionsProvider<T, V> : ICollectionsRepository<T, V> where T: Collection<V>, new() where V: CollectionItem
{
    private readonly string _file = Path.Combine(XmlProvider.DataStorePhysicalPath, typeof(T).Name + ".xml");

    public T Load()
    {
        if (!DefaultsExist()) {
            CreateDefaults();
        }

        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        T obj = null;
        XmlDictionaryReader reader =
            XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(new FileStream(_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                                                                                     new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

        obj = (T)dcs.ReadObject(reader, true);
        reader.Close();
        return obj;
    }

    public void Add(V item)
    {
        T collection = Load();
        collection.Add(item);
        Save(collection);
    }
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Culture")]
public sealed class Cultures : List<LangCult>   {   }

[DataContract]
public class LangCult : CollectionItem
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public abstract class CollectionItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```